# Prevent app from reversing the screen and mouse movement on BlissOS

Tags: screen, android-x86, auto-rotation

I have installed the latest BlissOS on QEMU VM.
The app which I'm interest in works, but it reverses the mouse (dragging up will move the mouse to left, dragging down will move to right) and the screen.

[image]

Disabling auto-rotation didn't work.

Is it possible to avoid this app from reversing the screen?

Answer (score 1):

Solution found by changing Android's "set orientation" to landscape.

[image]

[image]